# Downsampling Images

Tags: swift, swiftui

My Image loading code looks like this:

```
final class ImageStore {
    typealias _ImageDictionary = [String: CGImage]
    fileprivate var images: _ImageDictionary = [:]
    
    fileprivate static var scale = 2
    
    static var shared = ImageStore()
    
    func image(name: String) -> Image {
        let index = _guaranteeImage(name: name)
        
        return Image(images.values[index], scale: CGFloat(ImageStore.scale), label: Text(verbatim: name))
    }
    
    static func loadImage(name: String) -> CGImage {
        guard
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "jpg"),
            let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as NSURL, nil),
            let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load image \(name).jpg from main bundle.")
        }
        return image
    }
    
    fileprivate func _guaranteeImage(name: String) -> _ImageDictionary.Index {
        if let index = images.index(forKey: name) { return index }
        
        images[name] = ImageStore.loadImage(name: name)
        return images.index(forKey: name)!
    }
}
```

I have 300 images and their average size is 500 kb(3000px X 3000px).

I show them with `LazyVGrid`. After load approximately 250 images, memory use reach up to 1GB and app crash.

I found that every pixel occupies 4 byte(1 for red, 1 for green, 1 for blue, 1 for alpha) in RAM and this results 36 MB Memory footprint for each image. (3000x3000x4). See [here](https://swiftsenpai.com/development/reduce-uiimage-memory-footprint/).

Above link suggest that downsampling could help to reduce Memory footprint.

Here is the downsampling code:

```
func downsample(imageAt imageURL: URL,
                to pointSize: CGSize,
                scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale) -> UIImage? {

    // Create an CGImageSource that represent an image
    let imageSourceOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL, imageSourceOptions) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    // Calculate the desired dimension
    let maxDimensionInPixels = max(pointSize.width, pointSize.height) * scale
    
    // Perform downsampling
    let downsampleOptions = [
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
        kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxDimensionInPixels
    ] as CFDictionary
    guard let downsampledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, downsampleOptions) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    // Return the downsampled image as UIImage
    return UIImage(cgImage: downsampledImage)
}
```

I merged above 2 codes with like this:

```
final class ImageStore {
    typealias _ImageDictionary = [String: CGImage]
    fileprivate var images: _ImageDictionary = [:]
    
    fileprivate static var scale = 2
    
    static var shared = ImageStore()

    // Perform downsampling
    let downsampleOptions = [
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
        kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 950
    ] as CFDictionary //Added this block
    
    
    func image(name: String) -> Image {
        let index = _guaranteeImage(name: name)
        
        return Image(images.values[index], scale: CGFloat(ImageStore.scale), label: Text(verbatim: name))
    }
    
    static func loadImage(name: String) -> CGImage {
        guard
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "jpg"),
            let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as NSURL, nil),
            let image = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, downsampleOptions) //Added this line
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load image \(name).jpg from main bundle.")
        }
        return image
    }
    
    fileprivate func _guaranteeImage(name: String) -> _ImageDictionary.Index {
        if let index = images.index(forKey: name) { return index }
        
        images[name] = ImageStore.loadImage(name: name)
        return images.index(forKey: name)!
    }
}
```

But I get this error:
`Instance member 'downsampleOptions' cannot be used on type 'ImageStore'`

**How can I downsample the images?***(In other words, I need thumbnails for the image gallery)*

Comment: Put `static` before `let downsampleOptions`